# Creating an inclusion table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make an inclusion table using Pandas and being new to the language, I'm super confused. I'm working with facebook data.

Here's a sample of the data that I have:

the following is a collection of users with all of the pages that they like

```
id   pageid1    pageid2   pageid3     
10   123         456        789
11   478         166        356    ...
12   984         456        789
13   166         356        123
               ...
```

I also have a list of the most popular liked pages so

```
pop_page1: 123
pop_page2: 456
pop_page3: 789
     ...
```

so "pop_page1" is the most popular page liked by the users in my dataset.

when I'm all done, I want it to look like this

```
individual    pop_page1     pop_page2    pop_page3       (etc)
10             True          True          True
12             False         True          True
13             False         False         True
(etc)
```

basically I want to see if each user likes the most popular pages and I don't know how to do that in Pandas (or natively in python without messing up the data)

Comment: What is an "inclusion table"? Can you modify your question to include a copy/pastable version of what you tried already? And lastly, can you explain if and how `pop_pageN` relates to `pageidX`? (it's pretty clear that `id` maps to `individual`, but I would clean that up too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `DataFrame.isin()`:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
    pageid1  pageid2  pageid3
id                           
10      123      456      789
11      478      166      356
12      984      456      789
13      166      356      123

[4 rows x 3 columns]

In [13]: pages
Out[13]: [123, 456, 789]

In [14]: df.isin(pages)
Out[14]: 
   pageid1 pageid2 pageid3
id                        
10    True    True    True
11   False   False   False
12   False    True    True
13   False   False    True

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

In your question is wasn't clear how the popular pages was stored. I just made it a list, but if it's a `dict` you can use the `.values()` method to get them.

Comment: Wow that was exactly what I needed. I guess I just didn't see that in the documentation. 

They were stored in a list by the way. 

Thanks a lot!